# How to move in a resized and cropped bitmap?

Tags: c#, drawing

In .net core I have a controller that returns a random image. Let's say I have a Smiley. When I call localhost/1000/1000, it returns a smiley image with a width and a height of 1000 px each.

[image: smiley]

When I call localhost/500/1000, I cropped it:

[image: smiley2]

So far I have done this.

```
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,width,height);

        rect.Intersect(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height));

        image = ((Bitmap)image).Clone(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);

        var returnedImage = ImageUtils.ToStream(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        return returnedImage;
```

Instead of having half of the smiley, I would like to crop from the center like this:

[image: smiley3]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(image.Width / 4, 0, width, height);
```

Edit (adding explanation): starting the rectangle at the first quarter of the image makes it cover the part you need, so if you want the right half, then you'd start at `image.Width / 2`.